# How to filter out coordinates that are too close?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, coordinates

I have an array of coordinates like so (it's just a sample):

```
47.554730,18.963960
47.552670,18.962850
47.552310,18.963400
47.552080,18.963720
47.551870,18.964060
47.551780,18.963840
47.551690,18.963300
47.551540,18.962310
47.551480,18.961990
47.551440,18.961800
```

I would like to filter out coordinates which are too close to each other in order to reduce size. How can I achieve this?

**I have an idea:**

Set a number as the tolerance range.
Loop through every coordinate in the array and check if the difference between them is smaller than the tolerance range number, if it is, delete one of the coordinates.

Would this work? If yes, how could i code this in Objective-C?

Comment: Your array should not like this. If left column is latitude and right is longitude. it should be array of dictionay i think or array of dictionary. or there should be two different arrays for latitude and longitude

Comment: what should be output in your case?

Comment: There is a reason why it is like this, thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: If everything is in one array then how you can compare? you will compare latitude with longitude?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tolerance check, but it shouldn't be between the latitude and longitude values directly, it should be a tolerance on the distance, in meters, between the geographical location represented by the latitude and longitudes. The nature of latitude and longitude means you can't tell the physical distance between 2 points just by looking at the values.

To do this you can create instances of `CLLocation` from the lat/long pairs and then use `distanceFromLocation:` to tolerance check them.

You need to decide how you're going to choose which locations to keep and which to drop. There are many options for this, many of which require multiple loops to ensure that no 2 points are close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *Array1 = @[@"47.551090,18.961610",
                    @"47.551010,18.961600",
                    @"47.550910,18.961600",
                    @"47.550830,18.961610",
                    @"47.550750,18.961640",
                    @"47.550690,18.961680",
                    @"47.549980,18.962870",
                    @"47.549170,18.964170",
                    @"47.548950,18.964500",
                    @"47.548840,18.964620",
                    @"47.548710,18.964690",
                    @"47.548470,18.964690",
                    @"47.548400,18.964690",
                    @"47.547990,18.964720"];

NSMutableArray *finalArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CGFloat threshhold=0.0009;
for (NSString *str in Array1) {
    NSArray *temp=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    if(temp!=nil && [temp count]==2){
        BOOL isSame=NO;
        for(NSString *s in finalArr){
            NSArray *temp2=[s componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            if(([[temp objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[temp2 objectAtIndex:0]]) || ((((NSString*)[temp objectAtIndex:0])).floatValue-threshhold<=(((NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:0])).floatValue && (((NSString*)[temp objectAtIndex:0])).floatValue+threshhold>=(((NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:0])).floatValue)){
                isSame=YES;
                break;
            }

            if([[temp objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:[temp2 objectAtIndex:1]]){
                isSame=YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isSame==NO){
            [finalArr addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalArr);
```

You can set threshold value according to your requirement

Comment: note also that 2 equal latitudes with different longitudes could be many miles apart in the real world...